# Unable to access a published Asp.net site in IIS from browser

Tags: asp.net, .net, error-handling, publish

I have developed an Asp.net website and I am able to access it from my browser and also in LAN. Now I tried to publish the website and place the published website in my virtual directory and access it from my browser. This gives me an error.
[image]

> Configuration Error

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.  
Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.
This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

To my knowledge if the site is published , then when I give the URL upto the directory containing the site's files, then automatically the `Default.aspx` file should be opened, but I get the directory listing instead. If I open the Default.aspx from there, I get the error.

So please let me know why am I getting the error when I am accessing through the published site and also what's the difference in accessing the site being published or unpublished?

**Update:** My IIS screen shot:

[image]

Comment: What version of IIS have you used? What steps did you take to create the website in IIS?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Are IIS and its modules installed correctly (ASP.NET support, Default Document, Windows Authentication)?

Comment: @DanielCasserly IIS 5.1. Created a virtual directory in IIS. Created a website in the virtual directory, and published it in another folder in the same directory. Now I run this published site and it doesn't work. However running the website that was created works. Hope you got my last sentence.

Comment: @CodeCaster The screen shot that I put above is the error. I guess the installation is fine since I am able to access the unpublished sites. Problem only with published sites.

Comment: @Cdeez no, the screenshot you posted is the _source_ of the error, not the actual error.

Comment: @CodeCaster Updated the question with the error message.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted? The question does makes sense right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows server 2003 , You have to add "Default.aspx" to Default page list by right click on your site and then go to documents

To resolve your error right click on your site and then go to directory security and uncheck integrated windows authentication .

do not forget to run IISReset command

Comment: Xp operating system, IIS 5.1. Integrated windows authentication is already unchecked.

Comment: right click on MySite and choose create virtual directory and make it reading from Publish folder

Comment: Publish folder must be virtual directory to make the web.config inside it the primary web.config for that directory .

Comment: I did that and I get resource not found :( And why can't I access the site having <authentication mode=windows>. Only if I delete the line I am able to access the site in case of unpublished site. In case of published one it gives a different error in the page directive tag line

Comment: you can access site after deleting authentication tag because it is placed in sub-folder , when you completely delete this web.config you will get invalid reference exception

Comment: Hey sorry I did a mistake, created the virtual directory inside the Mysites virtual directory after your second comment. I now created a separate virtual directory like Mysites for published sites and now that worked. Thanks. Update your answer with your second comment.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the published file, and republish it. If it is not working, delete this line, and run it.

To set the Default.aspx is your home page, right click on virtual directory -> Settings -> Document (tab) -> add the Default.aspx and set it to first.

Comment: Delete which line? authentication mode=windows? I tried that by removing this line before I publish. I get a different a error now.